# 3 hours ago the distance to 10 a.m is as twice as the distance to 1 hour. What time is it now?

Tags: problem-solving

The question in the title. I think the answer is 11:00 a.m but I am not sure.

Comment: The exercise should be not in the title. What do you mean by "1 hour"? 1 a.m or 1 p.m. ?

Comment: What does "distance to 1 hour" mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but this is a DLR(German Aerospace Center) test question and I did not change it at all. I am having a hard time to understand it too...

Comment: Perhaps it's a translation issue...might help to post in in German as well.

Comment: The original question is in English. I did not translate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three hours ago it was 12 o’clock or 4 o’clock p.m.